# My texture and normal bake was unsuccessful - is it possible to paint over this to cover up some of the damage?

Tags: texture-painting, texture-baking, baking

I have baked my character (rather unsuccessfully), and am wondering if there is a way to paint over the dark/light areas that didn't bake properly.

[image: baked mesh texture painting]

Currently, when I try to texture paint over them, the dark patches still show through:

[image: texture painting]

Comment: It appears you are trying to paint the color map. That won't work because the artifacts are not in the color map, they are in the normal map, messing up the shading/lighting.
What I would recomend is to try and bake the normal map again, changing the settings until you get a good result.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will be helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQPjIGncXcM&ab_channel=Jayanam

Comment: Try to increase the *Extrusion* value (like 0.02). It extrudes the low-poly mesh so the starting point of the rays that are used for normal calculation is shifted. The *Max Distance* value is useful when you have problems with mesh parts that face each other, like the legs, armpits, chin and chest.

Comment: Okay thank you! Can I bake over it or should I start again and retrieve an older save?

Comment: You can bake over it. There is an option "Output > Clear Image" in the baking settings. It's enabled by default and Blender will start from scratch when you bake. Don't forget to save the image when you're happy with the result.

Comment: Thanks @Blunder all of that worked! Life saver :D